# SFDX retrieve does not fetch all custom objects

Tags: custom-object, salesforcedx

I have an unpackaged source that I want to retrieve (package.xml is below) using sfdx. The retrieve command succeeds without errors, but out of the 35 or so custom objects, only 3 get retrieved -- these are the ones that don't have __c suffix.

I'm using the following command on a Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6:
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve --verbose -r ./mdapipkg -u [scratch-org-name] -k ./package.xml

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

The package.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <members>AnalyticsEvent__c</members>
        <members>Product2</members>
        <members>AddressAttribute__c</members>
        <members>Address__c</members>
        <members>Category__c</members>
        <members>Contact</members>
        <members>CustomerPromotion__c</members>
        <members>CustomerSpecialInstruction__c</members>
        <members>Discount__c</members>
        <members>GoogleCloud__c</members>
        <members>Negative__c</members>
        <members>OrderAdjustment__c</members>
        <members>OrderItem__c</members>
        <members>OrderSpecialInstruction__c</members>
        <members>Order__c</members>
        <members>PersonAccount</members>
        <members>Project__c</members>
        <members>Promotion__c</members>
        <members>ProofFormat__c</members>
        <members>ProofPhoto__c</members>
        <members>ProofReviewer__c</members>
        <members>ProofRevisionHistory__c</members>
        <members>ProofRevisionSurfaceOverlay__c</members>
        <members>ProofRevisionSurface__c</members>
        <members>ProofRevision__c</members>
        <members>ProofSpecialInstruction__c</members>
        <members>ProofSurface__c</members>
        <members>Proof__c</members>
        <members>Response__c</members>
        <members>SampleRequest__c</members>
        <members>ShipmentOrderItem__c</members>
        <members>Shipment__c</members>
        <members>StringAttribute__c</members>
        <members>UploadedPhoto__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>SystemMessages/LargeDiscountAlert</members>
        <members>SystemMessages/MissingProofAlert</members>
        <members>SystemMessages/ShipmentShippingDelayAlert</members>
        <members>SystemMessages/CustomerOrderAdjustmentNotification</members>
        <members>SystemMessages/CustomerShippingNotification</members>
        <members>SystemMessages/EditRequestsDelayedNotification</members>
        <members>SystemMessages/EditsComplete_ToCustomer</members>
        <members>SystemMessages/NegativeTotalAlert</members>
        <members>SystemMessages/ProofLockExpired</members>
        <members>SystemMessages/ProofReassignedAlert</members>
        <members>SystemMessages/ReminderToApproveProof</members>
        <members>SystemMessages/ReminderToApproveProof2nd</members>
        <members>SystemMessages/ReminderToApproveProofFinal</members>
        <members>SystemMessages/ShipmentGenerationFailed</members>
        <members>SystemMessages/ShipmentPrintingCallbackFailed</members>
        <name>EmailTemplate</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <version>38.0</version>
</Package>
```